# Read an xml document and updating its content into listview by using loop in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, loops, listview, linq-to-xml

I have pushed the first node of xml document in the listview but not able to update all the nodes
I have used the xelement property of xml document.
I have even used the serialization method but its not working on my ide

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("saved_data.xml")
     Dim node As XElement = XDocument.Load("saved_data.xml").Root
     For Each nodes In node
            Dim str(2) As String
            Dim itm As ListViewItem
            str(0) = node.<data>.<NAME>.Value
            str(1) = node.<data>.<PHONE>.Value
            itm = New ListViewItem(str)
            ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
            str(0) = Nothing
            str(1) = Nothing
        Next
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to guess at what the XML looked like but this should help,

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'for production
    ' xe = XElement.Load("saved_data.xml")
    'for testing use a literal

    xe = <root>
             <data>
                 <NAME>one</NAME>
                 <PHONE>one ph</PHONE>
             </data>
             <data>
                 <NAME>two</NAME>
                 <PHONE>two ph</PHONE>
             </data>
             <data>
                 <NAME>three</NAME>
                 <PHONE>three ph</PHONE>
             </data>
         </root>

    For Each data As XElement In xe.<data>
        ListView1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}  {1}", data.<NAME>.Value, data.<PHONE>.Value))
    Next
```